# Who is "the Desire of all Nations" in Haggai 2:7?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, messiah, book-of-haggai

Haggai 2:7 mentions "the Desire of all Nations", according to modern day Judaism, is this a reference to the Messiah or to God Himself?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16204#showrashi=true) translation might help explain the phrase

> And I will shake up all the nations, and they shall come [with] the precious things of all the nations. And I will fill this House with glory, said the Lord of Hosts.

The translation (Judaica Press) jibes with the 1917 JPS [translation](http://www.breslov.com/bible/Haggai2.htm#7)

> And I will shake all nations, and the choicest things of all nations shall come, and I will fill this house with glory, saith HaShem of hosts

The reference is to neither a messiah or God, but to the desirable things brought by the other nations (detailed in verse 8 as, for example, gold and silver).